# How to run two for loop together?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested-loops

In my code I want to vary two parameters which are "i" and "t". The value of "i" and "t" will vary like, if t=1:10 and  i=(t+1):11  then,

at first I need to get the value for i = 2 3 4 5 .... 11 and for t=1

then I need to get the value for i = 3 4 5 .... 11 and  for t=2

then I need to get the value for i= 4 5 .... 11 and for t=3

. . .

I need to get the value for i= 8 9 .... 11 and for t=10

My code is like below:

```
        W=12;

        for t=1:10
          for i=t+1:11        
            s{i} =(fullfact(ones(1,i)*(W + 1)) - 1);
            B{i}= unique((sort(s{i}(sum(s{i},2) == i,:),2)),'rows');
            B{i}(B{i} == 0) = inf;
            A{i}= sort(B{i}, 2);
            A{i}(A{i}==inf) = 0;    
            idx = (A{i}(:,i-t)==1 );
            A {i,t+1}= A{i}(idx,:);
        end
     end
```

So, The value of A should be 9 columns and 10 rows. But i am not getting like this.
Need help from MatLab experts!

Comment: you have i=1:5 which doesn't go up to 10.

Comment: sorry it should be i=1:10. Updated please check.

Comment: what is W? what size?

Comment: W=12, Can you check now @NKN

Comment: this part will produce an error: idx = (A{i}(:,i-t)==1 ); when i==t.

Comment: But please look at now I have modified the condition t=1:10 and i=(t+1):11

Comment: So, i will never be equal to t

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there

```
oneLessThanTStart = t-1;
for t=1:oneLessThanTStart
  for i=0:10

  end
end
```

Should be mentioned I've never seen matlab.

Comment: indexing in matlab starts at 1 not 0!! so maybe i=1:11.

Comment: I am not clear what is t=1:oneLessThanTStart t should vary from 0 to (i-1).

Comment: @marianoc84 I have tried using t in the external loop but still the code is not working. I am not sure what are the things that I need to change additionally. It would be great help if you please let me know.

Comment: Since you swap index, i thought you should make some change in code even, have you done that? Post a code that we can run on our own.

Comment: I have updated the code. You can run this by yourself but not getting desired value. @marianoc84

Answer (score 0):

`t` loop should be external:

```
for t=1:9
   for i=1:(t-1)
        // it could be necessary swap some t with i and vice versa
   end
 end
```

Let me know. This is about [nested loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_nested_loops.htm) rather than Matlab.